# Yii2 Rest não consigo enviar o campo Nome de outra Tabela

Tags: php, yii

Como faço para enviar o nome do Funcionário que está na tabela Funcionarios para aparecer na requisição de um `REST`?

Sou novato, ele aparece no view que testei, mas não acho a maneira correta de enviar por `REST`.

a tabela Asos tem o idFuncionario
e a tabela Funcionario tem o idFuncionario
E não tem `FK` porque é `myIsam`.

MODEL

```
public function getFuncionarios()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Funcionarios::className(),['idFuncionario'=>'idFuncionario']);
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
class DefaultController extends ActiveController
{
   public $modelClass = 'app\models\Asos';
}
```

model -> [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/nwillian/seguramedicina/src/7510b4d830ba7c51bc42c8ac63db591cc0df3f6d/models/Asos.php)

Controller -> [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/nwillian/seguramedicina/src/7510b4d830ba7c51bc42c8ac63db591cc0df3f6d/modules/api/controllers/DefaultController.php)

Comment: Você quer exibir os dados relacionados pelo método `getFuncionarios()`?

Comment: Isso, ou se tiver uma outra forma mais fácil

Comment: Qual o erro que está sendo exibido? Como você está chamando a `API`?

Comment: Não aparece nada, simplesmente não aparece nada, eu utilizo o postman para teste, estou chamando dessa forma no controller


    public function actionIndex()    {
        $query = Cidade::find()->with('cTUF');
        return new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
    }